# What is architecture specific about libtool?

Tags: fedora, packaging, libtool

Fedora packages `libtool` as 64-bits:

```
# rpm -qi libtool |grep ^Arch
Architecture: x86_64
```

However, a superficial look at the package contents doesn’t show any obvious
arch specific binaries:

```
# rpm -ql libtool |xargs file
/usr/bin/libtool:                          a /usr/bin/sh script, ASCII text executable, with very long lines, with escape sequences
/usr/bin/libtoolize:                       a /usr/bin/sh script, ASCII text executable, with very long lines, with escape sequences
/usr/share/aclocal/libtool.m4:             M4 macro processor script, ASCII text, with very long lines
/usr/share/aclocal/ltargz.m4:              M4 macro processor script, ASCII text
/usr/share/aclocal/ltdl.m4:                M4 macro processor script, ASCII text
/usr/share/aclocal/ltoptions.m4:           M4 macro processor script, ASCII text
/usr/share/aclocal/ltsugar.m4:             M4 macro processor script, ASCII text
/usr/share/aclocal/ltversion.m4:           M4 macro processor script, ASCII text
/usr/share/aclocal/lt~obsolete.m4:         M4 macro processor script, ASCII text
/usr/share/doc/libtool:                    directory
/usr/share/doc/libtool/AUTHORS:            ASCII text
/usr/share/doc/libtool/ChangeLog:          Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with LF, NEL line terminators
/usr/share/doc/libtool/NEWS:               ASCII text
/usr/share/doc/libtool/README:             ASCII text
/usr/share/doc/libtool/THANKS:             UTF-8 Unicode text
/usr/share/doc/libtool/TODO:               ReStructuredText file, UTF-8 Unicode text
/usr/share/info/libtool.info-1.gz:         gzip compressed data, max compression, from Unix, original size modulo 2^32 312124
/usr/share/info/libtool.info-2.gz:         gzip compressed data, max compression, from Unix, original size modulo 2^32 51735
/usr/share/info/libtool.info.gz:           gzip compressed data, max compression, from Unix, original size modulo 2^32 4355
/usr/share/libtool:                        directory
/usr/share/libtool/build-aux:              directory
/usr/share/libtool/build-aux/compile:      a /usr/bin/sh script, ASCII text executable
/usr/share/libtool/build-aux/config.guess: a /usr/bin/sh script, ASCII text executable
/usr/share/libtool/build-aux/config.sub:   a /usr/bin/sh script, ASCII text executable
/usr/share/libtool/build-aux/depcomp:      a /usr/bin/sh script, ASCII text executable
/usr/share/libtool/build-aux/install-sh:   a /usr/bin/sh script, ASCII text executable
/usr/share/libtool/build-aux/ltmain.sh:    POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable, with escape sequences
/usr/share/libtool/build-aux/missing:      a /usr/bin/sh script, ASCII text executable
/usr/share/licenses/libtool:               directory
/usr/share/licenses/libtool/COPYING:       ASCII text
/usr/share/man/man1/libtool.1.gz:          gzip compressed data, max compression, from Unix, original size modulo 2^32 3469
/usr/share/man/man1/libtoolize.1.gz:       gzip compressed data, max compression, from Unix, original size modulo 2^32 3027
```

Which raises some questions:

Where is the architecture specific part? Some compile time constants
baked into those macro files? Would a 32-bit libtool accidentally packaged
as `noarch` break 64-bit builds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `libtool` script itself embeds its default host and build architectures, so it is different on each architecture it’s built for.

At least two other variables in `libtool` are architecture-dependent:

- the library search path;
- the linker command (it specifies the target format).

The rest of `libtool` is architecture-independent, and some other distributions split the package up so that they can provide an architecture-dependent package containing only the `libtool` script, and an architecture-independent package containing everything else.

Using the wrong `libtool` will indeed break your builds (it won’t find the right libraries, and linking will fail), unless they provide the correct values for the affected variables.

Comment: I just diffed the 32-bit and the 64-bit versions and none of the auxiliary files show any changes, just the ``libtool`` script. It mostly sets *defaults* like the arch triplet for the compiler and linker. On our multilib setup many 64-bit packages actually build regardless of which libtool arch is present because the relevant values are overridden at build time. Thus I take the observation that some don’t as indicative of insufficient isolation of our builds which have some of the defaults leak through.

Comment: Good point about overriding the defaults, I’ll update my answer...